# Библиотека SDL1.2 не работает в Sublime text

Tags: c++, sublime-text, sdl

Не могу заставить работать библиотеку SDL1.2, появляется ошибка при компилировании

```
main.cpp:1:21: fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL/SDL.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Вот сам файл сборки g++.sublime-build

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-Wall", "-ansi", "-pedantic-errors", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lmingw32", "-lSDLmain", "-lSDL", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
    "selector": "source.cpp",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "shell": true
}
```

Работаю в windows, компилятор использую g++

Comment: G++ не знает о папке, в которой установлен SDL. Попробуйте добавить в список аргументов компилятора «-D*путь_до_папки_с_SDL-ными_заголовками*».

Comment: Не совсем понял. Например: вместо "-lSDLmain" написать "-lС:/MinGW/lib/"?
п.с. Я библиотеку устанавливал в папку mingw, где и лежит собственно сам g++.

Comment: Если библиотека установлена рядом с mingw, то ничего добавлять не надо. Проверьте, лежит ли в `С:/MinGW/include/` (там MinGW ищет по умолчанию) папка `SDL` с файлом `SDL.h` внутри.

Comment: Да, все на месте.

Comment: Добавил параметр `-m32` для обращения к 32 битному компилятору, видимо. И еще закинул библиотеки в под папку папки MinGW: `C:\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include` `C:\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib` Теперь компилятор стал выдавать следующее: `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/../../../..‌​/x86_64-w64-mingw32/‌​lib/libSDLmain.a(SDL‌​_win32_main.o): In function console_main':` `/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL-1.2.15/./src/main/win32/SDL_w‌​in32_main.c:315: undefined reference to SDL_main'` `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status` `[Finished in 0.2s]`

Comment: Добавил параметры `int argc, char *argv[]` в функцию int main() и все заработало.

Comment: ShitCode: пожалуйста, [**перенесите своё решение из комментария в ответ**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2408/199934). Помимо всего прочего, Вы можете заработать репутацию за ответ. Спасибо.