# Компиляция кода SDL2

Tags: c, windows, mingw, sdl2, sdl

Я действую по простой инструкции [отсюда](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/), то есть каждый раз записываю в консоль:

1. пути: `-I"C:/…/include/SDL2"` и `-L"C:/…/lib"`
2. флаги: `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`
3. и сам простой файл `min.c` в UTF-8, который у меня таков:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Quit();
return 0; }
```

Но у меня ничего не получается, поскольку выходит ошибка:

```
min.c:1:10: fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <SDL/SDL.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Ну а заголовочные файлы по указанному пути действительно имеются?

Comment: @user7860670 конечно, это же папка "i686-w64-mingw32"

Comment: Ответ неверный, заголовочных файлов по указанному пути нет, о чем вам и сообщает компилятор. И, конечно, не стоит захламлять ими папки mingw.

Comment: @user7860670 я это понимаю, но я скачал архив с оф.сайта, и распаковал его на диск C, но компиль не видит, проверил ещё сейчас

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571066/178576)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я это видел, но с этого совета я и начал, так что проблема либо в компиле, либо в системе…

Comment: либо в действиях пользователя: `-I"C:/…/include/SDL2"` → `-I"C:/…/include"`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я проверил, консоль переходит по моим путям, так что эта папка стабильна. Может я неправильно совмещаю папку sdl и компиль mingw

Comment: путь к файлу `SDL.h` как выглядит? вероятно, что-то вроде `C:/…/include/SDL2/SDL.h`. а подключение его в коде выглядит как `#include <SDL/SDL.h>`. вот значит опцией `-I` и надо передать путь к `C:/…/include`, а не к `C:/…/include/SLD2`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну, не сработало. Вариантов уже, видимо нет, тч. попробую на другом компе

Comment: Если у вас такие сложности с написанием пути, то найдите файл `SDL.h` в проводнике, выделите его, нажмите в тулбаре кнопку "Скопировать путь", затем вставьте этот путь как аргумент `-I` в команду и удалите `SDL/SDL.h` с конца.

Comment: @user7860670 для примера, я поместил подпапки в директорию C, и использовал пути: `-I"C:\include"` и `-L"C:\lib"`. Всё равно не получилось. На другом компе тоже не выходит, так что ошибка у меня

Comment: Установите себе MSYS2, установите необходимые пакеты через pacman, и забудете о проблемах... И ещё, желательно выполнять сборку программ через терминал MSYS2.